# Driver for Epson Stylus C70 for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, epson

I see solutions for other Epson printers however my epson C70 is an older printer and not supported by other solutions I have seen.
Does anyone know of a solution for the C70.

Thank you for any assistance given.
David

Answer (score 0):

Here are drivers for Epson STYLUS C70 for Linux.  Information about Epson STYLUS C70 Linux Driver v.1.0., and to download it, [Click Here](http://driverscollection.com/?file_cid=3897512833597aaf3921ff44ba2).